# Dealing with mouseenter and mouseleave on the iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a typical looking drop down menu that is hidden by default but by the following jQuery magic

```
<ul class="navNew">
    <li  class="test">
        <a href="#">OPTION</a>
        <ul>
            <li>Suboption -- Hidden</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

$(".navNew li").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('hover');                                  
});
```

So with a mouseenter and a mouseleave, the class "hover" is added to the menu to make it visible or toggle it off to make it invisible again.

This all works like a charm, problem is on the iPad.  A single click will act as a mouseenter, but clicking the button again does not act as a mouseleave, and so the menu never closes again.  Can this code be modified so that a click will open and close this menu as well?

I've created a jsFiddle to explain what my menu is doing:  http://jsfiddle.net/qgrt5/

Comment: use the "onclick" event http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Comment: @JoeDF I still wanted to maintain the hover function as well.  If I add a click to the bind, then clicking does work, but if you move your mouse away after you click it will toggle the hover so it will be reversed (visible when mouse is off)

Comment: humm... does this help? http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_events_mouseover

Comment: @JoeDF not really? My code as it is functions on mouseover already.  The question is if click can be added to this functionality

Comment: could you do jsfiddle ? :)

Comment: Just add a class of open or closed ...

Comment: @JoeDF Yes, there is a fiddle, look up :) :)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/qgrt5/

**Edit**: The below code will now check if the user is coming from an iPad, and if they are, it will use the `click` function instead of the `mouseenter`

```
var isiPad = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;

if (isiPad) {
    $(".navNew li").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('hover');                                       
    });
}
else {
  $(".navNew li").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('hover');                                       
   });
}
```

Comment: It does work with click, but I wanted to maintain the hover functionality as well.  The key here is to have click work in addition to the hover so that it will function in hover

Comment: @Mark I've updated so that it uses both click and hover - and detects ipad

Comment: This won't detect any other type of tablet. iPads are a minority.

Comment: Simply use $(...).on('click mouseenter')

Comment: This makes no sense. What is the point of the if/else statement? The same exact code is executed regardless of the conditional. Its literally pointless.