# Mouseenter Mouseleave on iPad

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad

I am working on this [website](http://weierweg-liestal.ch/wohnen/), and as you can see I have a table animated via JavaScript. On `mouseenter mouseleave` on the table's rows you can display a different `<img>` on the right.

On desktop and Android it works, but not on iPad.

This is **a part** of the JS Code I'm using:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(document.body).on("mouseenter mouseleave", ".row1", function() {
        $('.two_1').toggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: See whether its working for you http://stackoverflow.com/a/15600735/4913153

Comment: I tried but nothing...